# SDL window close because of SDL_Flip with an image surface array

Tags: c, arrays, sdl, sdl-image

I am in the beginning of a game of brick breaker type and I'm stuck in the `SDL_Flip` step. My CodeBlocks compiler says nothing and the console doesn't crash, but yet the SDL window shutdown and the console process returned code 3. When I ran the debugger it says:

```
SDL_Flip()
Display(Bricks=0x28f69c, screen=0x0)
```

and the Display type error was said located at the line of my `SDL_Flip(screen);`

Here's a glimpse of my code. My `Brick_Coordinates` and `Brick_Surface` struct are already initialize (my coordinates for `Brick_Coordinates` and NULL for `Brick_Surface`) by another function before that one:

```
void Display(BrickStruct Bricks[12][10],SDL_Surface *screen)
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if( (j+1)%2==0 )  // If we are on even lines, display only 11 bricks
        {
            for(i=0;i<11;i++)
            {

                Bricks[i][j].Brick_Surface = IMG_Load("BrickTest1.png");
                SDL_BlitSurface(Bricks[i][j].Brick_Surface, NULL, screen, &Bricks[i][j].Brick_Coordinates);
                SDL_Flip(screen); 

            }
        }
        else   // If we are on odd lines, display the 12 bricks
        {
            for(i=0;i<12;i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct BrickStruct
{
    int type;
    SDL_Rect Brick_Coordinates;   
    SDL_Surface *Brick_Surface;  
}BrickStruct;
```

In my main, my code is like this:

```
SDL_Surface *screen= NULL; 

BrickStruct Bricks[12][10];  // I create my 2D array of struct named Bricks

Display(Bricks,screen);
```

I've already tested with a `fprintf` the values of my coordinates initialized. These are good. And apparently my `SDL_Blit` is working. But The Flip isn't. My screen surface is big enough for all my images (480x540 and my images are 40x20). I was wondering if that problem has to do with an impossibility for `Blit` to place an image on top of another but the `Flip` doesn't even work when I try with only one image (without my loops).
Can somebody please have the kindness to indicate me where is located my problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Call flip only once, after you blit every image, I really suggest your look at some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had first done. I moved the Flip just for the debuging but before I do that I had the same problem. And for the record I've followed a 2 weeks C lessons at school and followed after a very big C tuto (in order to have 2 differents point of view) which took me 2 weeks to finish and which have a full part about SDL and SDL_Image. Even like that I'm surprised to found myself stuck in front of things I have never encountered before. In my opinion I shouldn't have a hard time like that to print a PNG with SDL_image.

Comment: And by the way, I think my 2D array of structures of structure of surfaces is too uncommon to find something like that in tutorials on the web. And my teacher is a 19 years old child (What a school !) and don't give a sugar about my problem. He's saying LetMeGoogleThatForYou.

Comment: Forget this code, learn from tutorials and then go from there.

Comment: ? That exactly what I'm doing. Maybe I'm not using the best or simplest way to display all the block on my screen but I don't really know how else I can do it

Comment: Load an image *once*. Then display it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There reason was that that you didn't save screen into the global variable.

You probably had a line in your `SDL_Initialisation` similar to this:

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 8, SDL_SWSURFACE);
```

This creates a new local variable called screen. Since you wanted to save this into the global one, you should change it to:

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 8, SDL_SWSURFACE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I've already declared my screen pointer in my main. So that makes it (sreen) a global variable right ? And in `Void SDL_Initialisation(SDL_Surface *screen)` I'm just doing `SDL_Init` and `screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);`.
Like that, screen should be changed in a global way, no ?

Comment: No, a global variable is declared in the global scope. Not inside of any function, even main.

Answer (score 1):

According to your debugger and your example code your `screen` structure is null. So your call to `SDL_BlitSurface` will fail. The reason it probably works for you when you do your Display call inside your Initialize is that you've just initialized your `screen` and used it right after.

You need to store the surface you are writing to and use it again when you're blitting.

Also, as others have recommended, you should take a look at a tutorial for SDL and perhaps some more C tutorials to reinforce some concepts.